# Typescript debugging mocha tests with VSCode

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, typescript, mocha.js, visual-studio-code

I am having problem with breakpoints in VisualStudio Code. Refer to following image of my project

[image]

All my tests are written inside `test` folder and using gulp tasks they are transpiled to build folder. The build folder looks like below
[image]

The generated js.map has following information

> {"version":3,"sources":["test/modules/subscriber/index-test.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":";...lots
>   of js map code
>   here","file":"test/modules/subscriber/index-test.js","sourceRoot":"..\..\..\.."}

I have configured launch.json for vs code with following

```
   {
        "name":"Debug mocha test",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "node",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "args": ["--recursive", "build/test"],
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--nolazy"
        ],
        "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        },
        "externalConsole": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/build"
    }
```

When I launch this configuration, mocha is able to find the tests and execute it but it doesn't halt at the breakpoints specified in .ts files. I tried changing sourceRoot and other options but it simply not working.

**UPDATE**
With Jasmine framework, I am able to run and debug the test cases using typescript. I have moved with Jasmine, not sure why mocha is not running.